# Cefsharp redirect a popup

Tags: c#, vb.net, cefsharp

Using Cefsharp I am able to trap popups being opened using OnBeforePopup, what I now need to do is to show the popup content in the previous calling window.

Any help appreciated please.

Code So Far:

Public Function OnBeforePopup(browserControl As IWebBrowser, browser As IBrowser, frame As IFrame, targetUrl As String, targetFrameName As String, targetDisposition As WindowOpenDisposition, userGesture As Boolean, popupFeatures As IPopupFeatures, windowInfo As IWindowInfo, browserSettings As IBrowserSettings, ByRef noJavascriptAccess As Boolean, ByRef newBrowser As IWebBrowser) As Boolean Implements ILifeSpanHandler.OnBeforePopup

```
          RaiseEvent PopupRequest(targetUrl)
          popupInfo = windowInfo
```

The Popup window information now exists but does not have a handle for the window created at this point

Public Sub OnAfterCreated(browserControl As IWebBrowser, browser As IBrowser) Implements ILifeSpanHandler.OnAfterCreated

I believe this is the point that the popup window handle is created and this is where I need help in displaying that window in the original calling window and not as a new popup

Comment: Assuming you mean `OnBeforePopup`, just call `browser.Load` with the url and `return true` to cancel loading the popup.

Comment: Please take the time to format your code, it's near impossible to read currently. It's really not clear what your asking now. Are you trying to load the `popup` in the same browser instance and maintain the parent relationship?

Comment: I am using my iPad and the code is not formatting for some reason, but yes I am trying to load the popup in the same browser instance and maintain the parent relationship.